# Why WHILE is more efficient than FOR in this python function

Tags: python

**SUBJECT**: Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
**CODE**:

```
import time
import string
import random

class Solution:


    def getRandomStr(self,length):
        s = ""
        for x in range(0,length):
            s += random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits)
        return s

    # O(n)
    def hasValue(self,s,v,p,r):
        for k in range(p,r+1):
            if s[k] == v:
                return True
        return False

    # O(n^3)
    # if s[j] is found in prestr , 
    def lengthOfLongestSubstringWhile(self,s):
        
        maxlen = 0
        i = 0
        j = 0
        exitsign = False
        t0 = time.clock()
        while i < len(s):
            j = i+1
            while j < len(s):
                if self.hasValue(s,s[j],i,j-1):
                    maxlen = max(maxlen,j-i)
                    break
                elif j == len(s)-1:
                    maxlen = max(maxlen,j-i+1)
                    exitsign = True
                    break
                j+=1
            if exitsign:
                break
            i+=1
        # print maxlen

    def lengthOfLongestSubstringFor(self,s):
        maxlen = 0
        exitsign = False
        for i in range(0,len(s)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
                if self.hasValue(s,s[j],i,j-1):
                    maxlen = max(maxlen,j-i)
                    break
                elif j == len(s)-1:
                    maxlen = max(maxlen,j-i+1)
                    exitsign = True
                    break 
            if exitsign:
                break
        # print maxlen

    
S = Solution()
s = S.getRandomStr(10000)

t0 = time.clock()
S.lengthOfLongestSubstringWhile(s)

t1 = time.clock()
S.lengthOfLongestSubstringFor(s)
t2 = time.clock()

print t1-t0,t2-t1
```

This is the result:

> 0.187118
>
> 0.868182

Finished in 1.2s

Why the function with `while` is more quick than the one with `for`?

Comment: This is not very idiomatic Python, I guess your first language is C-like. For example, instead of `for i in range(0, len(s))` we write `for i, char in enumerate(s)`

Comment: you are right. I began to use Python this Monday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, `range` is generating and throwing away a ton of arrays of numbers as loop indexes in the "for" version.  Like, 10000 arrays averaging 5000 items each.  Try replacing `range` with `xrange` (the generator version) and you won't do that as much.

Comment: I did it as you say, and it's fixed up.Thank you very much!

Comment: If you could "accept" my answer that would be great :)

Comment: it's my first time to use stackoverflow.so how can I accept it?